# My website running on LiteSpeed, but when i do test results are: Running on: Imunify360-Webshield 1.8

Tags: testing, litespeed

I'm really getting strange problem when i do test on my website. I use LiteSpeed server, but when I do tests, through a varvy or some other well-known sites, the results are strange. It shows results and files that my site doesn't use. It also shows that I'm using another server which is really weird server like Running on: Imunify360-Webshield 1.8. My hosting provider can't explain this. I'm sure the problem is not with the hosting, because I've changed 5 hosting sites in different territories and the results are still the same.

When I try to test another page from the same site for example: https domain.com/service I get Timeout reached. If i do test without https:// for example only www.domain.com/service i get Running on: Imunify360-Webshield 1.8

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple, the provider (or providers you use), are using Imunify360 on their servers, and have the Imunify360-webshield enabled, likely the test sites you're using are blocked by the firewall, and thus end up hitting the webshield.